# MATLAB "C" DLL Errors

Tags: c, dll, matlab

I'm compiling some MATLAB functions into a C DLL. The exported `mlf` functions return a boolean value representing whether the function succeeded or not. When the return value is false, I want to find out the error information. I couldn't find a way to do that! (other than compiling and exporting the `lasterror()` function).

Is there a C interface to get the last error generated by MATLAB's runtime?

Comment: did tou ever find a solution to this?

Comment: The only solution I found was to compile and export a function that returns the results of the "lasterr()" function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, let's try...

[**mexCallMATLABWithTrap**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/apiref/mexcallmatlabwithtrap.html) (C and Fortran) - Call MATLAB function, user-defined M-file, or MEX-file and capture error information

```
#include "mex.h"

mxArray *mexCallMATLABWithTrap(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[], const char *functionName);
```

and

[**mexEvalStringWithTrap**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/apiref/mexevalstringwithtrap.html) (C and Fortran) - Execute MATLAB command in caller's workspace and capture error information

```
#include "mex.h"

mxArray *mexEvalStringWithTrap(const char *command);
```

Those two things were found with Google and a guess or two. Sorry if it's a waste of time.